# How to invoke a function at an exactly given time point in Python?

Tags: python, time

How to invoke a function at an exactly certain time point in Python?

For example:

```
import time
def foo():
    print time.time()

start_time = time.time()
expected_time_to_run_foo = start_time + 12.3456
#invoke foo
```

How to make the function `foo` print the given value `expected_time_to_run_foo`?

P.S.: I am not sure whether `time.sleep()` works. I need more precision.

Comment: More precise than `time.sleep(12.3456)`?. Unless you have a realtime OS, there will be limits to how accurate you can get it - certainly not down to 100's of microseconds.

Comment: Yes. Because the `foo` may take time to run itself before `print`, I'm afraid that `time.sleep()` is not precise enough.

Comment: See here for more on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python

Comment: I would look at some event based libraries (celery, gevent) they are more reliable than sleep. But I doubt would will find something more precise than seconds.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep

Comment: @gnibbler that single error is acceptable. but I need to call the `foo` many times. the accumulated error would go bad I think.

Comment: So arrange to call using start_time as an absolute reference

Comment: This is all very system-dependent. I run a version of Ubuntu from linuxcnc.org on my CNC machines. It uses [RTLinux](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?RealTime), which uses realtime kernel extensions to try to gain more accuracy, which can be important in CNC applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in sched module will let you schedule events for the future.  (All the code here is Python 3).

```
import sched
import time

def print_something(x):
    print(x)

s = sched.scheduler()

s.enter(1, 0, print_something, ['first'])
s.enter(2, 0, print_something, ['second'])
s.run()
```

You can provide your own functions to get the current time and to wait until a specified time in the future.  The defaults are time.monotonic (a tweaked version of time.time) and time.sleep.

You can get a slight accuracy increase using a busy-wait, like so:

```
import sched
import time

def print_something(x):
    print(x)

def busy_wait(target):
    while time.monotonic() < target:
        pass

s = sched.scheduler(delayfunc=busy_wait)

s.enter(1, 0, print_something, ['first'])
s.enter(2, 0, print_something, ['second'])
s.run()
```

But, realistically, there are so many sources of unexpected delay in a desktop OS that if your timing constraints are that tight, you will never get acceptable results without a realtime OS.

Comment: thanks. it works. the single error is acceptable. I just worried about the accumulated errors which would not occur in this approach.