# Getting today's date in YYYY-MM-DD in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Is there a nicer way than the following to return today's date in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

```
str(datetime.datetime.today()).split()[0]
```

Comment: maybe this? \n 
now = datetime.datetime.now() \n 
str(now.strftime("Y-%m-%d")

Comment: @Gombat What I mean is in my experience, there's usually a built in way of getting the thing we want in Python without having to split, index, concat, join etc.

Comment: [pandas and pendulum alternatives are available for those working with these libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55371556/4909087)

Answer (score 1599, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2021-01-26'
```

To also include a zero-padded `Hour:Minute:Second` at the end:

```
>>> datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2021-01-26 16:50:03'
```

To get the UTC date and time:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2021-01-27 00:50:03'
```

Comment: there is also a strong probability that "%x" would work ... but that is locale dependent

Comment: how about just `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`?

Comment: For UTC date: `datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Worth noting that `date` has this available as well as `datetime`

Comment: Here's a helpful list to get variations of OPs desired result: https://strftime.org/

Comment: Upvoted. Here's my favorite format: `datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.%f")`. Example output: `'20230803-195136.416752'`. The meaning is `YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.microseconds`. That's "Year Month Day - Hours Minutes Seconds.microseconds". I use this commonly for auto-sorting log files and temporary files.

Answer (score 245):

You can use [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) and convert the resulting [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object to a string:

```
from datetime import date
today = str(date.today())
print(today)   # '2017-12-26'
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the separator to `/`?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro it would be `date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Bad idea. The reader normally assumes the separator `.` to 'D.M.Y', the separator `/` to `M/D/Y` and the separator `-` to `Y-M-D`. Although not everybody follows these guidelines, it would help reading dates internationally as long as not everybody has switched to `Y-M-D`.

Comment: @glglgl I’m working with an api that assumes the American date format m/d/y. I’ve already changed the order in my application.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro But then you'd need `M/D/Y`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I am using m/d/y

Comment: This is the best answer because more explicit `.date` is used instead of `.datetime` which requires stripping out the time.

Comment: A short answer: `datetime.date.today().isoformat()` --but even shorter: `str(datetime.date.today())`

Comment: String value of date in str( datetime.date.today() ) is different than that in str( ( datetime.date.today() ) ). -- another place where the legacy behaviour of repr and str is non-intuitive.

Answer (score 98):

I always use the [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) method for this.

```
from datetime import date    
today = date.today().isoformat()
print(today)  # '2018-12-05'
```

Note that this also works on [`datetime` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) if you need the time in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format as well.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today().isoformat()
print(now)  # '2018-12-05T11:15:55.126382'
```

Answer (score 95):

Very late answer, but you can simply use:

```
import time
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# 2024-02-22
```

Answer (score 52):

Datetime is just lovely if you like remembering funny codes. Wouldn't you prefer simplicity?

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2017-02-17'
```

This module is clever enough to understand what you *mean*.

Just do `pip install arrow`.

Addendum: In answer to those who become exercised over this answer let me just say that arrow represents one of the *alternative* approaches to dealing with dates in Python. That's mostly what I meant to suggest.

Comment: for a simple task like this, why use another library when built-in library can do it as simply.   
Of course, if user need other multitude of {time, date}-related functions, bringing in a new library makes sense.

Comment: you made me laugh on reading that 2nd line of code. how's that better than `print(date.today())` >> "2018-12-16"?? lol and easily get the int values `t.year,t.month,t.day+1` >> (2018, 12, 17) where `t = date.today()` and the fact people don't have to call green arrow to tell them the time. oh god this is too much code to remember...

Comment: @Puddle: Hilarious.

Comment: @kmonsoor How is `import datetime` different than `import arrow`? Sure one is built in, but if `arrow` provides a more convenient format, then why not use it?

Comment: @information_interchange you already answered your question. Built-in vs not. If someone needs those extra stuff, sure, why not `arrow`? But, for many simple projects, it's just unnecessary. Also, in many company-internal projects, ppl need to get approval for including new libraries.

Answer (score 36):

## Are you working with Pandas?

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) from the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) library. Here are various options, depending on what you want returned.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime('today')  # pd.to_datetime('now')
# Timestamp('2019-03-27 00:00:10.958567')
```

As a python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) object,

```
pd.to_datetime('today').to_pydatetime()
# datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 3, 50, 42, 587629)
```

As a formatted date string,

```
pd.to_datetime('today').isoformat()
# '2019-04-18T04:03:32.493337'

# Or, `strftime` for custom formats.
pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# '2019-03-27'
```

To get just the date from the timestamp, call `Timestamp.date`.

```
pd.to_datetime('today').date()
# datetime.date(2019, 3, 27)
```

Aside from `to_datetime`, you can directly instantiate a [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) object using,

```
pd.Timestamp('today')  # pd.Timestamp('now')
# Timestamp('2019-04-18 03:43:33.233093')

pd.Timestamp('today').to_pydatetime()
# datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 3, 53, 46, 220068)
```

If you want to make your Timestamp timezone aware, pass a timezone to the `tz` argument.

```
pd.Timestamp('now', tz='America/Los_Angeles')
# Timestamp('2019-04-18 03:59:02.647819-0700', tz='America/Los_Angeles')
```

---

## Yet another date parser library: Pendulum

This one's good, I promise.

If you're working with [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/), there are some interesting choices. You can get the current timestamp using `now()` or today's date using `today()`.

```
import pendulum 

pendulum.now()
# DateTime(2019, 3, 27, 0, 2, 41, 452264, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

pendulum.today()
# DateTime(2019, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
```

Additionally, you can also get `tomorrow()` or `yesterday()`'s date directly without having to do any additional timedelta arithmetic.

```
pendulum.yesterday()
# DateTime(2019, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

pendulum.tomorrow()
# DateTime(2019, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
```

There are various formatting options available.

```
pendulum.now().to_date_string()
# '2019-03-27'

pendulum.now().to_formatted_date_string()
# 'Mar 27, 2019'

pendulum.now().to_day_datetime_string()
# 'Wed, Mar 27, 2019 12:04 AM'
```

---

#### Rationale for this answer

A lot of pandas users stumble upon this question because they believe it is a python question more than a pandas one. This answer aims to be useful to folks who are already using these libraries and would be interested to know that there are ways to achieve these results within the scope of the library itself.

If you are not working with pandas or pendulum already, I definitely do not recommend installing them just for the sake of running this code! These libraries are heavy and come with a lot of plumbing under the hood. It is not worth the trouble when you can use the standard library instead.

Comment: Great news pandas has it too!

Comment: This one is really awesome, specifically when one's working on pandas

Comment: pd.to_datetime(day).date() is useful if you're using pandas and don't want to convert to a str. Thanks!

Comment: @cs95 The main question is "How to get YYYY-MM-DD format". Not "how to get the current date". Your answer is irrelevant. You can try to extend it by stripping everything after "YYYY-MM-DD" to answer the question.

Comment: For "pendulum" use:  `now = pendulum.now()`, `now = now.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko I disagree with the premise, there are actually two questions here. I've focused on the first one, because the answer to the second one is less interesting (strftime). Besides, this answer is useful for those who want the date object and not the date string.

Answer (score 12):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.today().date()

print(date)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is a longer/worse variant. Prefer the shorter `str(datetime.date.today())`

Answer (score 10):

Use f-strings, they are usually the best choice for any text-variable mix:

```py
from datetime import date
print(f'{date.today():%Y-%m-%d}')
```

Taken from [Python f-string formatting not working with strftime inline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65145502/11154841) which has the official links as well.

Answer (score 9):

If you need e.g. pacific standard time (PST) you can do

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
datetime.now(tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# '2021-09-02 10:21:41'
```

Answer (score 2):

my code is a little complicated but I use it a lot

```
strftime("%y_%m_%d", localtime(time.time()))
```

reference:'https://strftime.org/

you can look at the reference to make anything you want
for you what YYYY-MM-DD just change my code to:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime(time.time()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
from datetime import date
today =date.today()
```

Output in this time: 2020-08-29

Additional:

```
this_year = date.today().year
this_month = date.today().month
this_day = date.today().day
print(today)
print(this_year)
print(this_month)
print(this_day)
```

Comment: Try not to use python built in functions and variables as local variables (ex: today, year, day). Also, the request from the user is to get today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format. Can you try and answer to the question (format YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 1):

If you were already using `numpy`, `numpy.datetime64` could be used to get today's date as well. Then simply cast it into a string (or use `np.datetime_as_string`) to get its string representation in ISO 8601 format.

```py
import numpy as np

np.datetime64('today')                         # numpy.datetime64('2023-09-17')
np.datetime_as_string(np.datetime64('today'))  # '2023-09-17'
str(np.datetime64('today'))                    # '2023-09-17'
```

Answer (score -3):

To get day number from date is in python

for example:19-12-2020(dd-mm-yyy)order_date
we need 19 as output

```py
order['day'] = order['Order_Date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```