# Python f-string formatting not working with strftime inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, f-string

I'm hitting an odd error that I'm trying to understand. Doing some general code cleanup and converting all string formatting to f-strings. This is on Python 3.6.6

This code does not work:

```
from datetime import date
print(f'Updated {date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}')

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(f'Updated {date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}')
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, this (functionally the same) does work:

```
from datetime import date
d = date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(f'Updated {d}')

Updated 11/12/2018
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious, and am fine with the second iteration, but I want to understand what's happening here.

Comment: note the colors in your question: you have to use a different set of quotes. Do `print(f'Updated {date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}')`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There's a native way:

```py
print(f'Updated {date.today():%m/%d/%Y}')
```

More on that:

- [PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting -- Controlling Formatting on a Per-Type Basis](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#controlling-formatting-on-a-per-type-basis)
- [`datetime.date.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__)

Answer (score 12):

```
print(f'Updated {date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}')
```

Your code was prematurely ending the string definition.

Comment: Wow, yep, super obvious. Thanks for pointing out the stupid mistake!

Comment: `print(f'Updated {date.today():"%m/%d/%Y"}')`

Answer (score 3):

if string is part of another string you need to use double quote in one of them

```
(f"updated {date.today().strftime('%D')}") # %m/%d/%y can also be written %D
```

Comment: escaping the (inner) single quotes would also work, though there's no reason to prefer that here. `f'updated {date.today().strftime(\'%D\')}'`

Comment: Ah, nice tip on %D. Where did you find this? I can't find that reference anywhere in documentation.

Comment: i found it here ' https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm ' some of which are not in documentation i guess

Answer (score 2):

Strangely this has not been proposed:

```
print(date.today().strftime("Updated: %m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: a funnier way to use f strings with strftime:
    var = 'Updated'
    print(date.today().strftime(f'{var}: %m/%d/%Y'))