# Get today's date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This was supposed a simple lookup from pandas' documentation but I've failed: How can I get today's date in pandas' `TimeStamp` as a local date without time component or today midnight.

I thought that `TimeStamp.today()` was supposed to give the desired result but instead I am getting time now, meaning following **always** evaluates to `True`:

```py
pd.Timestamp.today() == pd.Timestamp.now() # True
```

Comment: What time format are you looking for (ISO8601, etc.)?

Comment: Are you looking for `pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some options:

```
# As a timestamp
pd.Timestamp.today().floor('D') # .normalize() does the same thing
# Timestamp('2019-08-05 00:00:00')

# As a date object
pd.Timestamp.today().date()
# datetime.date(2019, 8, 5)

# As a YYYY-MM-DD string
pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# '2019-08-05'
```

[More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55371556/4909087)