# Adding email subject line with changing date to list of "accepted subjects"

Tags: python, email, datetime

I have to add a subject line to a list of other subject lines. This is normally an easy task, except this time, the email subject line always includes the date it was sent. How would I include this into my code?

Basically, I have the subject line "YYYY-MM-DD_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line" and I want to add anything that matches the first date part+the rest of the string to a list.

```py
changning_date_subject = str(datetime.strptime('', '%Y-%m-%d')) + '_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line'
accepted_subjects = [changing_date_subject, 'Other Static Subject1', 'Other Static Subject2', 'Other Static Subject3']
```

I get ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'", and while I understand why it would say that an empty string doesn't match, I can't really add a hard-coded string because it will change each time. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Getting today's date in YYYY-MM-DD in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490629/getting-todays-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-in-python)

To get the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format, use:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

In your code, this would look like:

```
from datetime import datetime
changing_date_subject = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line'
accepted_subjects = [changing_date_subject, 'Other Static Subject1', 'Other Static Subject2', 'Other Static Subject3']
```

Note: I fixed a typo in your variable from `changning_date_subject` to `changing_date_subject`

Comment: And if it's not today, but any date?

Comment: How do you get the date value that you want to add to the subject line? e.g., does it come as a string, or as a datetime object?

Comment: It's as a string, basically the subject lines I get are:
2019-08-03_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line
2019-08-05_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line
2019-07-31_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line

^ For example.

Comment: Sorry for that hideous formatting! I get them as below, where the date isn't necessarily today:   
`2019-08-03_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line`   
`2019-08-05_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line`   
`2019-07-31_Rest_of_Non-changing_Subject_Line`

Comment: I may have got confused -- are you trying to extract the date out of the subject line?

Comment: Nope! I just want to add the string that's in the subject line to a list, but the problem is that the date changes, thereby changing the string. I just want it to add any date that it may start with to the list, regardless of what date it is - it's not important. Is that clearer? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Where I'm running aground is that if you are already getting the subject (from some other process etc) - with the date already at the front - then to me it seems like you would just add the subject to your list, no need to manipulate anything. Maybe a better question from me is: why does it matter if the date part of the subject changes? What do you intend to do with it where that makes a difference?

Comment: I was just trying to retroactively get attachments from those emails, without trying to hard-code it for those dates. But going forward, I can use the "today" function so that's helpful anyways!