# Databricks python/pyspark code to find the age of the blob in azure container

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Looking for databricks python/pyspark code to copy azure blob from one container to another container older than 30 days

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- The copy code is simple as follows.

  ```
  dbutils.fs.cp("/mnt/xxx/file_A", "/mnt/yyy/file_A", True)
  ```
- The difficult part is checking blob modification time.  According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#dbutils-commands), the modification time will only get returned by using `dbutils.fs.ls` command on Databricks Runtime 10.2 or above. You may check the Runtime version using the command below.

  ```
  spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.sparkVersion")
  ```

  The returned value will be Databricks Runtime followed by Scala versions.
  If you get lucky with the version, you can can do something like:

  ```python
  import time
    ts_now = time.time()

  for file in dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/xxx'):
    if ts_now - file.modificationTime > 30 * 86400:
      dbutils.fs.cp(f'/mnt/xxx/{file.name}', f'/mnt/yyy/{file.name}', True)
  ```

Comment: Here time.time is giving time in seconds. Is there any method to give timeframe in yymmdd.

Comment: With reference to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490629/getting-todays-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-in-python), you may convert timestamp to any format you want.  First `dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)` then `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Hey Could you please help me with how do I navigate for the log file maintained by azure for the operation in azure lifecycle management policy.

Comment: It would be better to create a new question for that and see if someone can help.