# How to get today's date in SPARQL?

Tags: python, date, sparql

I use Python and SPARQL to make a scheduled query for a database. I tried to use the python f-string and doc-string to inject today's date in the query, but when I try so, a conflict occurs with SPARQL syntax and the python string.

The better way would be to use SPARQL to get today's date.

In my python file my query looks like this:

```
query = """
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    SELECT * {
    VALUES (?currentDateString) {(today)}

    FILTER(xsd:date(?dateApplicabilityNode) >= xsd:date(?validDateString) && xsd:date(?dateApplicabilityNode) <= xsd:date(?currentDateString))

    }
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

How to get today's date in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Comment: getting the current date in Python in the appropriate format has been asked and answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490629/getting-todays-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-in-pythonhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490629/getting-todays-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`now()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-now) returns the datetime (as `xsd:dateTime`) of the query execution:

```
BIND( now() AS ?currentDateTime ) .
```

To get only the date (as `xsd:string`), you could use [`CONCAT()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-concat) with [`year()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year), [`month()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-month), and [`day()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-day):

```
BIND( CONCAT( year(?currentDateTime), "-", month(?currentDateTime), "-", day(?currentDateTime) ) AS ?currentDateString ) .
```

(To get the date as `xsd:date`, you could use `xsd:date(?currentDateString)`.)

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I replaced the above two lines with the `VALUES (?currentDateString) {(today)}` line, but the query gives me an error. I have updated the query on the question. 
Could you help me?

Comment: @MahdiJafari: Try replacing your `VALUES {}` with my two `BIND` lines, and cast the string `?currentDateString` to `xsd:date()` in your `FILTER`.