# Issue with Python returning same timestamp several times

Tags: python, timestamp, real-time

I am working with an API that uses a callback function to send data for up to 2000 times per second. The body of the function gets the data argument (that the API calls the function using), appends a timestamp (using datetime.now().timestamp()) to it, then sends it to a queue, where it will be saved in a file after the acquisition has been finished.

The issue I am facing is that I am getting the same timestamps several times, with different data. Below is an example of some of the saved data:

Data------timestamp

3258    1595943590.058758

3246    1595943590.058758

3246    1595943590.058758

3248    1595943590.058758

3254    1595943590.058758

3246    1595943590.058758

I tried using time.time() instead and the issue was still there:

2986    1595944140.3182354

2986    1595944140.3182354

2984    1595944140.3182354

2984    1595944140.3182354

2984    1595944140.3182354

2986    1595944140.3182354

2986    1595944140.3182354

2982    1595944140.3182354

2980    1595944140.3182354

2986    1595944140.3182354

Is the issue that the API is sending data so fast that the time isnt updating fast enough? Is there a more accurate way to get time?

```
#part of a class
def apiFunc(self, data):
        if data:
                d = (data, time.time())
                self.storage.put(d)
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: Why do you consider it an issue?

Comment: @superbrain Because I want the exact timestamp for each data point for later synchronization and analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe combine the precision of `time.perf_counter` with the meaningfulness of `time.time`. Here's code and output (left is pure `time.time`, right is my suggestion):

```
>>> if 1:
    import time
    delta = time.time() - time.perf_counter()
    timestamps = []
    for _ in range(10):
        pure = time.time()
        mine = time.perf_counter() + delta
        timestamps.append((pure, mine))
    for row in timestamps:
        print(row)

(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029738)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029812)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029826)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.002984)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029855)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029874)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029886)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.00299)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.0029914)
(1595947258.0029619, 1595947258.002993)
```

Excerpt from a much longer output where the pure time finally changed (had to try thousands of rows):

```
...
(1595947517.2481732, 1595947517.2532165)
(1595947517.2481732, 1595947517.2532175)
(1595947517.2481732, 1595947517.2532187)
(1595947517.256172, 1595947517.2532716)
(1595947517.256172, 1595947517.253275)
(1595947517.256172, 1595947517.253278)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python), `time()` on windows only has ~16 milliseconds precision.

> The standard time.time() function provides sub-second precision, though that precision varies by platform. For Linux and Mac precision is +- 1 microsecond or 0.001 milliseconds. Python on Windows uses +- 16 milliseconds precision due to clock implementation problems due to process interrupts. The timeit module can provide higher resolution if you're measuring execution time.