# how to convert datetime object to time_ns

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch

I have the following problem I need to convert some datetime object to time_ns (present in time)

all I can find is to convert the now datetime to that fixed nanoseconds number (i understand that it is calculated from a fixed date in 1970)

```
import time
now = time.time_ns()
```

all I want is to convert some normal datetime object to that fixed nanoseconds number

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime(2022, 2, 22, 15, 41, 50)
```

i don't want to be restricted to only now dates. is there some function in the library that does that? for the moment i cannot find anything

thank you very much

Comment: you basically want [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). datetime objects have a method [timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) that gives you that in *seconds* since the Unix epoch, 1970-01-01 midnight UTC. Multiply by 10^9 to get nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since python 3.3 datetime has a timestamp function. Make sure to replace the timezone, otherwise local timezone will being taken and if you want to have nanosecond number you can multiply the seconds number.

```
from datetime import datetime; 
print(datetime(2022,2,22,15,41,50).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()*10**9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're just trying to convert `time.time()` or `time.time_ns()` into a date and time instead, use `time.localtime()` or `time.gmtime()`.

See the various reference documentation descriptions for each of those functions here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time:

Examples:

```py
>>> import time
>>> time.time_ns()
1691443244384978570
>>> time.localtime(time.time_ns()/1e9)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=20, tm_sec=57, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=219, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.time_ns()/1e9
1691443263.0889063
>>> time.localtime(time.time())
time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=23, tm_sec=22, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=219, tm_isdst=0)
```

That's all from my bigger answer here: [High-precision clock in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73482099/4561887)