# python: endless while loop with fixed frequency

Tags: python, loops, time, while-loop, frequency

in my programm i have a endless while loop which needs to run in a fixed frequency to give da constant datarate. My idea (which I copied from github) was to get a timestamp outside the loop and inside the loop, and use the delta as my frequency.

```
import time

time_after_loop = time.process_time() # initalisation
frequency = 0.05

while True:
    time_before_loop = time.process_time()
    if time_before_loop - time_after_loop >= frequency:
        real_frequency = time_before_loop - time_after_loop
        print(real_frequency)
        # main programm
        time_after_loop = time.process_time()
```

I use windows 10 and python 3.8 and the print values show some interessting behavierous

frequency = 0.5  --> real_frequency = 0.5

frequency = 0.1  --> real_frequency = 0.109375

frequency = 0.05  --> real_frequency = 0.0625

frequency = 0.001  --> real_frequency = 0.015625 --> max frequency

It looks like a systematic error, not a problem in the code? Does someone know what happend here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

try using (`time.time()`) instead of `time.process_time()` and see if it gaves you a more accurate results.

```
import time

  time_after_loop = time.time() # initialization
  frequency = 0.1

  while True:
    time_before_loop = time.time()
    if time_before_loop - time_after_loop >= frequency:
      real_frequency = time_before_loop - time_after_loop
      print(real_frequency)
      # main programm
      time_after_loop = time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) instead of `time.process_time()`, as it includes time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide.

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide.

Output:

```
0.05000000004656613
0.05000000004656613
0.05000010004732758
0.050000099930912256
0.050000099930912256
0.05001329991500825
0.05000010004732758
0.050000099930912256
0.050000099930912256
0.05000000004656613
0.050000099930912256
0.05000010004732758
```

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like a systematic error, not a problem in the code?

I am not sure if this is case here but please note that `print` is not free timewise (it takes low but not zero time to `print`)

> Does someone know what happend here and how to fix it?

I suggest looking at [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), `Timer` might be used for *starting* execution of action every x seconds regardless of how much time said action is taking, consider following simple example which does endlessly print 2 times second (i.e. every 0.5 seconds)

```
import threading

def func(): 
    threading.Timer(0.5, func).start()
    print("Hello")

func()
```

Note that next execution of `func` is shoved into queue before proper action is taken.

Answer (score 0):

Python `time` is only accurate to +- 0.001 milliseconds for Linux and Mac and +- 0.016 for windows. Getting really really accurate is hard. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python) for more reading

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!! You helped me a lot

time.time()

and

time.perf_counter()

worked well

time.process_time() was the wrong function to use here!