# Python's time.time_ns() returns same value in consecutive calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

This Python script

```
import time

while True:
    ns = time.time_ns()
    print(ns)
```

prints lots of identical values (always non-decreasing though). I am using Python 3.10 and Windows 10. Looks like a clock precision issue. Is there a way to get strictly increasing values?

Comment: All the various options (`time.time()`, `time.time_ns()`, etc.) seems to be limited to Windows's ~16ms resolution. There may be some workable solutions here: [High-precision clock in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1938048/13843268).

Answer (score 0):

This class seems to provide higher resolution timing:

```
import time

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._offset_ns = time.time_ns() - time.perf_counter_ns()

    def time_ns(self):
        return self._offset_ns + time.perf_counter_ns()
```