# Python timestamps not increasing on some platforms?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timing

I just tried the following little Python3 test:

```py
import time
tvar = 1
tsa = time.time()
tvar += 1
tsb = time.time()
print("tsb {} tsa {} tsb-tsa {}".format(tsb, tsa, tsb-tsa))
print("  rate {}".format(tvar/(tsb-tsa)))
tsc = time.monotonic()
tvar += 1
tsd = time.monotonic()
print("tsd {} tsc {} tsd-tsc {}".format(tsd, tsc, tsd-tsc))
print("  rate {}".format(tvar/(tsd-tsc)))
```

If I run this under https://replit.com/languages/python3 - then the script completes fine, and results I get are more-less expected:

```
tsb 1675886955.5210621 tsa 1675886955.5210614 tsb-tsa 7.152557373046875e-07
  rate 2796202.6666666665
tsd 23325.72801936 tsc 23325.728018751 tsd-tsc 6.090012902859598e-07
  rate 4926097.937479465
```

However, when I run the very same script under Python3 in MINGW64 shell (MSYS2 on Windows 10) which is currently version Python 3.10.9, the script actually crashes:

```
$ python3 test_time.py
tsb 1675887125.3224628 tsa 1675887125.3224628 tsb-tsa 0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\msys64\tmp\test\test_time.py", line 7, in <module>
    print("  rate {}".format(tvar/(tsb-tsa)))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

So, here the `tsb` and `tsa` timestamps ended up being *equal*, even if they are called separated by an assignment command (`tvar += 1`) - but even if the timestamp assignments were called one after the other, they *should* have shown a different value?

And the same problems appears with `time.monotonic()` as well (although the above example crashes before we get to that point).

So, is this Python3 behavior (i.e. on some platforms, `time.time()` or `time.monotonic()` can be called two times in a row, and return the exact same timestamp) expected; and is there anything I can do, to have timestamp behavior consistent across platforms (that is, at least: two subsequent (quick) calls to `time.time()` or `time.monotonic()` should result with not just differing timestamps, but with timestamps where the earlier timestamp is a smaller numeric value than later timestamp? (so that durations/time differences can never result with zero, which would otherwise cause division by zero when calculating rates)

Comment: Any reason you're not using `timeit`?

Comment: If the system's clock granularity is not small enough, you can call `time.time()` multiple times without the clock changing. `time.monotonic()` guarantees that it won't go backwards, but it doesn't promise that it will always increase each time.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - as far as I know, `timeit` is used to "measure execution time of small code snippets", but I don't want to really measure execution time of small snippets - I want to measure e.g. transfer rates I get over USB or network; but I'm keen to see an example of how to use `timeit` in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - the "doesn't promise that it will always increase each time" explains why also `time.monotonic()` might fail, which really suprised me at first; good to know this!

Comment: OK, then you need to repeat your data transfer enough times that the clock changes.

Comment: In general, when you're trying to time anything, you need to measure multiple repetitions or process a large input and calculate the average. Otherwise random variation will make the results meaningless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python