# High performance Python code for MODBUS PLC controller

Tags: python-3.x, performance, labview, modbus, plc

I working on a project where a MODBUS PLC controller (WAGO 750-891) is used to control a set of 100 valves (Festo MH1 3/2 way solenoid valve). The valves need to be switched a specific frequency which differs among the valves and can change in real time in accordance to the results of an image segmentation algorithm written in Python.

I am using the PC to control the PLC which behaves as MODBUS TCP client.

Currently I am working on  a single valve to test the code performance. The code turns on and off a single valve with a switching frequency of 20Hz for one minute. After that, the  elapsed time is printed.

In an ideal world the elapsed time should be around 60s, but in my case it  is around 75s(1 5.4 Hz). The code is executed from the terminal which is the only application open. The computer has a i5 11th generation and 16 gb of ram.

The main reason I chose Python is  because the segmentation algorithm is written in Python as well. I don't know if switching to other languages would affect the "communication" between the codes.

I am wondering if there are some ways to improve the code performances or if it is better to switch to other things like LabVIEW.  I tried Matlab but the code is even slower ( elapsed time: 88s) and using PyPy doesn't significantly improve the performance.

This is the code I am using:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from pymodbus.client.tcp import AsyncModbusTcpClient as ModbusTCPClient
async def single_valve_pumping_cycle(client, valve):
    i = 0 
    duration = 60  # in seconds 
    thread_frequency = 20  # Hz
    main_t1 = time.time()
    while i < duration * thread_frequency:
        await client.write_coil(valve, False)
        await asyncio.sleep(1 / thread_frequency)
        i += 1
        await client.write_coil(valve, True)
        await asyncio.sleep(1 / thread_frequency)
        i += 1   
    main_t2 = time.time()
    main_delta = [main_t2 - main_t1]
    print("The elapsed time is " + str(main_delta))
async def write_coils(client):
    await client.connect()
    await single_valve_pumping_cycle(client, 512)  
async def main():
    ip_address = '192.168.1.3'  # Replace with your PLC's IP address
    port = 502  # Modbus TCP port
    client = ModbusTCPClient(ip_address, port)
    await write_coils(client)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

EDIT1: I compacted the code to make it more readable

EDIT2: Thank you for the suggestion! I've modified to code to take into account the delay introduced by the Modbus in the following way:

```py
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    for i in range(n_cycles):
        #print("True")
        await client.write_coil(valve, False)
        await asyncio.sleep(thread_time - (time.monotonic()-start_time)%thread_time)

        await client.write_coil(valve3, False)
        await asyncio.sleep(thread_time - (time.monotonic()-start_time)%thread_time)
```

I started an asynchronous Modbus TCP server on my PC to test the code and everything works fine. However when I test the same code on the PLC I still have troubles. Should I start an asynchronous Modbus TCP server that has the same IP as the PLC?

Comment: I would time how long the modbus calls are (to a time delta for the await client.write_coil), the bottleneck here is more likely the comms (from both ends), rather than the programming language itself. Using C for example would gain you only marginal benefit. You could then adjust your sleep time to account for the comms delay.

Comment: See [High-precision clock in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python) for ways to determine how much time has passed since your last "tick", which will in turn allow you to compute how long you must sleep before the next "tick".

Comment: Your sleep time doesn't account for command execution time as @chrisbeardy says. Look at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/how-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds) to better account for this time.

Comment: I've edited the main message with the updates. Taking into account the delay helped a lot

Answer (score -2):

Are you displaying images using a falling water curtain? This is one of those utterly jaw-dropping things the first time you see it :-)

I don't know how much one should expect from Python asyncio but it would certainly be worth trying LabVIEW, probably using a [Timed Loop structure](https://www.ni.com/en/shop/labview/timing-and-synchronization-in-ni-labview.html) to do the Modbus command and a separate loop running in parallel to get the data from the Python code and pass it in to the timed loop - using either a queue if you don't want to lose any data or a notifier or local variable if you just want the latest values. You might be able to [call the Python code from LabVIEW](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview-api-ref/page/menus/categories/computer/python-node-mnu.html), or you might need to implement your own communication between Python and LabVIEW e.g. using TCP/IP or UDP.

If this isn't good enough then you may simply be up against the limit of what is possible using software timing on a desktop operating system. If you can change your hardware then you could use hardware timed I/O where you feed a buffer on the hardware device from your code, then the data is written out according to a hardware clock - LabVIEW and NI digital I/O hardware could certainly do this. Alternatively you might need to move to a real-time platform where the timing won't be affected by other processes - NI has LabVIEW Real-Time but this will cost extra if you don't already have a licence bundle, and you may need to run it on dedicated hardware too. Or if you already know PLC or microcontroller programming it might be more cost- and time-effective to put the real-time code on one of those platforms.

One obvious question, is your Modbus device the only one on the network, or could traffic between other devices be harming the network latency?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've just edited the main massage with some updates.