# Strange interaction of time.monotonic_ns and time.sleep

Tags: python, time, sleep

I have noticed that there is some strange behaviour when `time.monotonic_ns` and `time.sleep` interact with each other in a small time period.

To investigate this I have wrote the following "test".

```
import time

def main():
    while True:
        start = time.monotonic_ns()
        time.sleep(0.01)  # 10 milliseconds
        end = time.monotonic_ns()
        diff = end - start
        print("diff: {}".format(diff))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code most of the times prints a value of about `15000000` (actually exactly 15000000 ns or 16000000 ns) or `15` milliseconds, but sometimes it is just `0`.
If I decrease the sleep-time more it has the exact same behaviour (i.e. 15 ms or 0 ns).

When I use `time.time_ns` instead it will be non-zero every time (also more random and it sometimes even goes down to ~11 ms), `time.perf_counter_ns` also works fine. I am aware that `time.process_time` will be always 0 because it does not count sleep time. `timeit.timit` also shows a minimal sleep time of ~8 ms on my system.

I am on a Windows 11 device. According to the [python docs for time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) sleep has a resolution of 100 nanoseconds (which is clearly less than 10 milliseconds). For `time.monotonic_ms()` I was not able to find a resolution.

I can understand how it could be more than the 10 milliseconds specified but I have no idea how it could be 0 nanoseconds.
Python Version: 3.9.13.

I have also tested this on 3.12 with the only difference that IDLE freezes when I try to stop the execution with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73482099/476 — *"zero answers here on 12 July 2016 had any resolution better than 16-ms for Windows in Python 3.1."*

Comment: @deceze Bit 3.12 isn't 3.1, and none of the answers had talked about `monotonic_ns`.

Comment: @Kelly But it gives a clear hint that there's a problem with very short durations on Windows, even with monotonic clocks. I do not know if anything has improved since. It's just a pointer.

Comment: What do you see when you call `monotonic_ns` let's say a million times, look at the differences of adjacent times, and summarize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was made aware by [a comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python/1938096#1938096) (found by "link hopping" based on a comment here by user "deceze ♦") of a function called `time.get_clock_info`. This function provides clock-information of serval clocks (in the time-module).

This is the output for `time`:

```
namespace(implementation='GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()', monotonic=False, adjustable=True, resolution=0.015625)
```

As it can be seen the resolution is about 16 ms as I have seen before.
Apparently `monotonic` which is the timer for `monotonic_ns` (in general all `..._ns` timers are just specialized variants of the non-ns versions as it seems) has the same resolution (with a different base):

```
namespace(implementation='GetTickCount64()', monotonic=True, adjustable=False, resolution=0.015625)
```

This still does not deliver an answer why it is sometimes zero.
`perf_counter` has a higher precision:

```
namespace(implementation='QueryPerformanceCounter()', monotonic=True, adjustable=False, resolution=1e-07)
```

`process_time` has the same accuracy as `perf_counter`:

```
namespace(implementation='GetProcessTimes()', monotonic=True, adjustable=False, resolution=1e-07)
```

Python: 3.9.13 on Windows 11 Home (Edition of Windows seems to make a difference)

Edit: `time.monotonic_ms` seems to be only able to output multiples of 16ms. So it either outputs 16 (sometimes it is off by 1 ms, this could be based of a rounding error as the actual resolution isn't 16ms but 15.625ms) or 0 in case of a shorter time period (the same goes for 20ms where it alternates between 15/16 and 31/32 ms).

Comment: *"This still does not deliver an answer why it is sometimes zero"* — If the elapsed time is lower than the clock's resolution, it means the clock can't tell if any time has elapsed or how much. So "0" is as valid an answer as "16ms" in that case.

Comment: For some reason `time.time_ns`  displays time periods smaller than 16ms while `time.monotonic_ns` does not even both have the same resolution. I looks to me that `time.time_ns` is less "honest" so it looks like one should better use `time.monotonic_ns` (I guess `time.perf_counter` needs more cpu).

Comment: *"I guess time.perf_counter needs more cpu"* - For me, it's actually a bit [faster](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY4xDsIwDEX3nMJjgkoWFsRVEIqqyhYeYkfGHRg5B0uXciduA6Xlb0__S_89X-3uV5Vpmken_fH9INMKzhXZgWtTczBs2HvYaOlCIDUgYIHzwrmqqKvwUOTW_Sa5oVEZdBRHu8AODqcA3zRj8Ui5FOkrltJBZYnrRaSU0iqy-fy9Pg).

Comment: Oh but that's not Windows. What times do you get from that?

Comment: @KellyBundy I actually was just guessing why one normally does not use perf_counter (make it the default) when it is similar speed but with higher resolution. There could be also other reasons. For example it might be useful for it to be adjustable in some situation or whatever is another reason. I did run a similar test (also incl. `time_ns`). Result: `time_ns` and `monotonic_ns` both are at ~0.02 while `perf_counter` is 0.04 (on 3.9, on 3.12 both are about 0.01 slower) on my machine.